# Display Settings Window disappeared

Tags: 16.04, unity, nvidia, multiple-monitors

So I'm still with Ubuntu 16.04 on my Y700. I have installed the nvidia binary driver, though this happens with nouveau, too.
When I open the 'Display' settings I see my internal laptop screen and my external screen. (Both enabled, extended desktop)

When I disable the internal screen (e.g. to run a game on the external screen only) the settings dialog becomes unreachable. It seems it's in the desktop region that was displayed before. When I click on the Icon in the window switcher I can see both windows of Screen settings but none becomes visible.

Is there any keyboard shortcut or something else to move all windows in the current display / desktop region?

I tried to record a video but 'RecordMyDesktop' crashed when disabling the second screen...

Answer (score 1):

When that happens to me I usually right click the window tab on the task bar and click move [from the context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty8tV.jpg), after that just dragging the mouse (without clicking anything) to an active screen should work.

Comment: thanks for that, unfortunately this is not what my Ubuntu desktop looks like :/ I have a standard installation and I miss that context menu